# Uses of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, applications

This might not be a great question, but it comes to my mind from time to time:

“Are there some actual examples of mathematical or metamathematical results coming from research on topological spaces?”

I know some famous examples coming from Wikipedia entries, such as the “Königsberg bridges” or the “4 colours theorem” but these examples seem to belong more to graph theory than to general topology, since not once is an actual topological space mentioned in the proofs.

Don’t get me wrong, I love the subject, but sometimes I wonder if the way topology is developed has building  intuitions on mathematicians as it’s only (or primary) objective.
I think another underlying question is:
“What is it that makes topological spaces so important as a mathematical structure as to have a complete branch of mathematics for themselves?”

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes for a surprising example

Comment: Wow! It is surprising indeed! The best proof on prime infinity i’ve encountered. This one was great…thanks!

Comment: Decades ago there was an article in Scientific American on explaining why some heart fibrillation occurs in some circumstances because of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topology is quite relevant to the rest of mathematics. Making this a community wiki in case others want to add on.

**Logic**: the Axiom of Choice is equivalent the [Tychonoff Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem) on products of compact spaces.

**Data Analysis**: [Persistent homology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_homology) is used to measure the similarity of datasets.